# Intermediate table, populate it from .txt and distribute info

Tags: syntax, mysql-workbench

How do I create an intermediate table with information from a .txt file (the syntax), then populate the intermediate table with the information from the txt file. Also then I need to distribute in the main tables the information imported in the intermediate table (syntax). Help me with the syntax.

Comment: What system or software are you asking about? You need to give more information.

Comment: I use Mysql Workbench, thank you